# Why does CascadeType property of Hibernate only work for the children of the object and not for the children of the children?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am using Hibernate for my Java application, and I noticed that the CascadeType property only seems to work for the immediate children of an object, but not for the children of the children.

For example, suppose I have an **Product** object that has a **TextContent** object as one of its fields. If I set the CascadeType property to ALL on the Customer field, any changes made to the **Product** object will be automatically persisted when the **TextContent** object is persisted.

However, the **TextContent** has a list of **Translation** objects as one of its fields, and I set the CascadeType property to ALL on the translations field, changes made to the **TextContent** object will not be automatically persisted when the **Translation** object is persisted (the FK in the Translation is NULL instead of the id of the TextContent).

Why is this the case? Is there a way to make the CascadeType property work for the children of the children as well?

**Entities:**

```
public class Product {
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public TextContent textContentName;
}

public class TextContent {
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "textContent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Translation> translations;
}

public class Translation {
  private Integer id;

  private String translation;

  @ManyToOne()
  private Language language;

  @JsonIgnore()
  @ManyToOne()
  private TextContent textContent;
}

public class Language {
  private Integer id;
    
  private String acronym;
}
```

**JSON of the product sended to the controller:**

```
{
  "id": null,
  "textContentName": {
    "id": null,
    "translations": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "translation": "Product name in English",
        "language":{
          "id": 1,
          "acronym": "en"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": null,
        "translation": "Nombre del producto en Español",
        "language":{
          "id": 2,
          "acronym": "es"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**JPA Execution of the controller:**

```
productRepository.save(product)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason hibernate needs the reference of the **TextContent** object in the **Translation** object even though this reference is deducible from the child of **Translation** (**TextContent**).

I managed to solve it by modifying the setter of the **Translations** list of the **TextContent** entity passing from:

```
public class TextContent {
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "textContent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Translation> translations;

  public setTranslations(List<Translation> translations){
      this.translations = translations;
  }
}
```

to:

```
public class TextContent {
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "textContent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Translation> translations;

  public setTranslations(List<Translation> translations){
      translations.forEach((translation) => {
          translation.setTextContent(this);
      });
      this.translations = translations;
  }
}
```

Doing this when calling the `save()` method of a product creates both the **TextContent** object and the **Translations** associated with the same **TextContent**, which was not the case before.

Answer (score 1):

Associations in the domain model represent how different domain entities related to one another. often these relationships can be expressed as parent-child relationships.

Cascade works on records from parent and child tables that are directly related using F.key.

Because Hibernate JPA delegates referential integrity concerns to the foreign key constraints of the underlying SQL database.

There is a good reason for this design decision.  because can for example control the merging of a detached object at the association level.

So only those child that is in the association of your parent entity gets a cascade and not the child of the child.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've understood what `CascadeType` does.

1. It is *not* about synchronizing changes (updates) with the database. [By default] a change to an entity is *automatically* detected and synchronized to the database at flush-time, as long as the entity is associated with the persistence context when the persistence context is flushed.
2. Cascading is all about cascading *explicit* operations like `persist()`, `merge()`, `refresh()`, and `remove()`, and it is *definitely* always recursive.

I can't quite pinpoint the precise source of your confusion/problem, because you have not shown us any code.

Comment: When i create a "Product" the TextContent is created but the translations are created without the relationshit, the list of translations of the textcontent is empty

Comment: That means nothing to me. What does "create" mean? There's no operation in JPA or Hibernate called "create". C'mon man. Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: Create means when i execute save() in a product entity.

Comment: I see you have added *some* code now, but still not the code I need to see. (The code which calls the `Session`.)